# MS Access Subform adding multiple rows

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a form that I use for memo generation which I just added a new subform to which handles contract info. It is a small table which only has the PurchaseID (linked to the main table) and then the contract fields shown as text boxes/combo boxes.

My Issue: Originally what was happening was when a user didn't click into the sub-form shown, no row would be created in the Contract table. If you look at the picture, when the form loads the "PurchaseID" field is populated because it's an autonum linked to the main table. However even though that field is populated, if a user doesn't physically click into the sub-form, no row gets created. I just want the blank row with the default options to be added to the table.

My attempt to fix it: 
What I tried doing to fix this is on the event "On Current", I wrote 1 line of code that just sets the value of the combo box to a value. I think this sets the sub-form as a focus and it does end up creating the record. The problem is, now whenever the form loads, it initially tries to add a blank row with the ID of 0 to the Contract table, essentially making a duplicate blank row every time the form opens. I think the reason is because the "On Current" event is happening before the "PurchaseID" field is linking to the main table, resulting in a PurchaseID of "0" continuing to duplicate when the form is opened.

What I need:
Looking at the picture below. How do I make it so when a user does *not* click in that subform box when going through everything, a new record is added to the sub-form table with the default values selected (procurement/notrequired/etc.).

Picture of form. Sub-form that has issue is circled.

[image]

Comment: Change your code to add this before the line that adds the value:  IF PURCHASEID > 0 Then ...

Comment: Such a simple fix. Looks like this worked. Thank you sir =].